# [S1090][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Invalid string or buffer length

Tags: sql-server, unixodbc

I'm getting the error above when issuing

```
 isql 'odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=<redacted>;DATABASE=<redacted>;' username password -v
```

as root on my Linux CentOS 6.7.

The following bcp command works, so the driver should be working correctly:

```
bcp master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES out OutFile.dat -S <redacted> -U user -P password
```

Also this command works:

```
sqlcmd -Sg<redacted> -Uuser -Ppassword
```

Also this PHP script, if run from command line as root, will return an error:

```
<?php
$connStr = 'odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=<redacted>;DATABASE=<redacted>;';
$dbUser = '<redacted>';
$dbPass = '<redacted>';

$db = new PDO($connStr, $dbUser, $dbPass);
?>

[root@ru000397 ~]# php prova.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /root/prova.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /root/prova.php(6): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver={OD...', '<redacted>', '<redacted>')
#1 /root/prova.php(10): db_connect()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /root/prova.php on line 6
```

I already installed Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for Linux (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh568451(SQL.110).aspx) and unixODBC 2.3.0 without issues.

My main goal is to be able to connect to MS SQL instance via PHP PDO using ODBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDO connection couldn't find the driver for me when using the curly braces. After removing those, I was able to connect just fine.

**Note** my usage of the double quotes for the connection string which allows variable expansion.

```
$mssqldriver = 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server';
$connStr = "odbc:Driver=$mssqldriver;SERVER=<redacted>;DATABASE=<redacted>;";
```